# How to reinstall <alt>-<tab> after loss of it in Debian Wheezy linux?

Tags: debian-wheezy, alt-tab

After installing of a package (octave) with synaptic on Debian Wheezy I can not switch the tasks behind one window --- how can I change it to the original? Moreover together with that install synaptic updated about 500+ other packages ...

Comment: Evidently nobody of the Debian community reads this kind of questions!

Comment: I should add: I am using Gnome as desktop environment (DE)